# Windows Reinstall needed with RAID?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I currently am running a 500GB SSD as my boot drive, and a 1TB HDD on the side.
If i wish to put the 1TB HDD in RAID 1 would I need to reinstall Windows 7?
I don't believe that's how it works, but i just want to double check.
Thanks.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that i would use two of the same HDD's.

Comment: If you use raid 1 on an ssd and hdd, your ssd will be slowed down to the speed of the hdd. I highly do not recommend it. RAID 1 needs to be in sync with each drive.

Comment: @DylanRz I forgot to include that i would be using a second (same model) HDD, not RAIDing ssd + hdd. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: in that case its possible. I could create a guide for you but there are millions on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to reinstall Windows.  Windows will not let you turn the system drive into a RAID volume in software.  However, your data drive can be used in a RAID.

The first step you need to do is ***backup*** your information on the 1TB disk you want to use in the RAID. While it is not required that you format your disks for some of the RAID options, don’t take any chances and make a backup.

Once the backup is done, you can follow any online guide in using Windows Disk Management to mirror the two 1TB drives.

Comment: @alex416 if this answers your question, dont forget to mark it as the accepted answer